# mpv error with mp4 files in Wayland: "VA error: wayland: Wayland roundtrip error: Protocol error (errno 71)"

Tags: video, 21.04, wayland, mp4, mpv-media-player

Ever since the 21.04 switch to Wayland, mpv has been saying:

```
[vo/gpu/wayland] GNOME's wayland compositor is known to have many serious issues with mpv. Switch to GNOME's xorg session for the best experience.
```

and yet has been working flawlessly (including with mp4 files). Until now. This new problem only seems to occur with mp4:

```
wl_drm@22: error 0: authenticate failed
VA error: wayland: Wayland roundtrip error: Protocol error (errno 71)
[vaapi] libva: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with invalid VADisplay, driver_name = (null)
[vo/gpu/wayland] Error occurred on the display fd, closing
```

Any idea why the regression?

Update: If I use `--hwdec=no` the problem goes away. According to the man page, this is the default, so I'm guessing that it used to be, and the changing of the default is what happened recently (but they need to update the man page).

Update: See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mpv/+bug/1944088
for details. Problem was solved by a clean reinstall of 21.04 (with no PPAs)

Comment: Please file a bug report against mpv for this issue.

Comment: user535733 should this be done on launchpad (I am using mpv from Ubuntu repositories)? The mpv bug tracker on mpv.io/bug-reports seems aimed at people who compiled from a git version or release.

Comment: Yes, launchpad. One easy way is to use the `ubuntu-bug` application: `ubuntu-bug mpv` and follow the prompts.

Comment: Done. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mpv/+bug/1944088

Comment: @user1951615 As it looks from the result of your bug report, this wasn't a bug. So it would be nice if you could add an answer with your solution (mentioning the issue you had with `ppa-purge`). If you add one, please ping me in a comment using `@BeastOfCaerbannog` so I can upvote the answer. Thanks!

Comment: System76 has confirmed the problem and they are investigating. I expect this to lead to a more surgical solution than doing a clean Ubuntu re-install.